# Unrecognized option: -url while taking thread dump

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic12c

I using weblogic 12.1.3.0.0 and trying to take thread dump using command line via following command:

```
java -cp $CLASSPATH weblogic.Admin -url t3://urltoweblogicadminserver:7101 -username username -password weblogic THREAD_DUMP
```

I am getting following error:

```
Unrecognized option: -url
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I checked and all environment paths are fine still cannot pinpoint the error.
In short, i want to take thread dumps at specific intervals of my server

Comment: why do you think the `java` command should have an `-url` option?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use the WebLogic-specific command syntax described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/admin_ref/cli19.html). Is that correct? If so, then this is a WebLogic admin utility - not a standard `java` command. See [Required Environment for the weblogic.Admin Utility](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/admin_ref/cli.html#1327416).

Comment: try jmap, jstack , or kill -3 to take thread dumps: https://devwebcl.blogspot.com/2017/03/analyzing-wls.html

Comment: Hi All, thanks for you response, running setWLSenv.sh before calling the script or the above command worked.
I appreciate your time and response.